# String to hexadecimal conversion - Python - ValueError: Invalid conversion specification

Tags: python, type-conversion

I need to split a four digit string to two hexadecimal numbers.

Eg: string = "ABCD"
expected output = 0xAB 0xCD

I tried these statements:

```
>>data = "0000"
>>[byte1, byte2] = [data[:2], data[2:]]
>>byteInt = int(byte1,16)
>>byteHex = format(byteInt,'0#4x')
>>print byteHex
```

I am getting the error, "ValueError: Invalid conversion specification" at the line "byteHex = format(byteInt,'0#4x')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading zero in the format specification is not needed since you have not specified any alignment:

> `format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]`

`fill` is conditioned on alignment:

```
>>> byteHex = format(byteInt,'#4x')
>>> byteHex
' 0x0'
```

To use the optional `fill` in the format specification, you should specify an alignment:

```
>>> byteHex = format(byteInt,'0>#4x') # left align
>>> byteHex
'0x00'
```

Comment: It's working. Can you suggest me where I can learn more about 'format()'?

Comment: [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: There is another issue. If I use the "byteHex = format(byteInt,'0<#4x')", when the value of byteInt is 4, the output is 0x40, instead of 0x04. Can you help with that?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the arrow for left align. Should have been `>`.

Comment: I referred the link that you have sent. I found out that I should use '= ' instead. It is working now.